# Smoke is only connected to the object how do i fix this?

Tags: smoke-simulation

Smoke applied to the object "UV sphere" [image]Im trying out the smoke effects but when I spawn in them it lingers only around the object.

[image]

Comment: Hi and welcome. After you changed the settings or position you have to bake the simulation to see the changes.

Comment: I would highly recommend watching tutorials on the Mantaflow smoke simulation because there are lots of options and settings to get good results.

Comment: Saw a YouTuber that automatically got the smoke and could freely move the smoke around the object do I really have to bake for that? I am wondering what option he enabled to do that. @Blunder